# Цикл многострочной записи в файл с изменяющимися переменными

Tags: php, json

Всем привет!
Я совсем еще новичок и хочу разобраться с задачкой. Есть JSON с которым приходится постоянно работать и добавлять новые данные, но данные повторяются, меняются только значения. И неплохо сделать автоматизацию всего этого дела. Пример:

```
    <?php

    // Открыть текстовый файл
    $f = fopen("files/test.txt", "w");
    $id_col = 577;
    $cost = 3;


    // Записать строку текста
    fwrite($f, 
    "\t\t\t\"m$id_col\": {\n"
    ."\t\t\t\t\"cost\": $cost\n"
    ."\t\t\t},"
    );

    // Закрыть текстовый файл
    fclose($f);

    // Открыть файл для чтения и прочитать строку
    $f = fopen("files/test.txt", "r"); // параметр "r" - открытие файла только для чтения
    echo fgets($f); 

    fclose($f);

?>
```

Мне нужно что бы я мог записать последовательно 12 раз данные указанные в блоке записи в строку. Но при этом каждый раз переменная $id_col, должна расти на +1. И в некоторых шагах цикла, например 3,5,7 может изменится cost на 9 или 5.

Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону копать? Примерно понимаю что надо зайти через цикл for. Может быть есть более изящный способ работы с JSON? Мне нужно часто вырванный кусок JSON самому конфижить и вставлять в рабочий JSON.

В результате хочу получить такой кусок в текстовом файле:

```
    "m577": {
        "cost": 9
    },
    "m578": {
        "cost": 3
    },
    "m579": {
        "cost": 3
    },
    "m580": {
        "cost": 3
    },
    "m581": {
        "cost": 3
    },
    "m582": {
        "cost": 3
    },
    "m583": {
        "cost": 3
    },
    "m584": {
        "cost": 5
    },
    "m585": {
        "cost": 3
    },
    "m586": {
        "cost": 3
    },
    "m587": {
        "cost": 3
    },
    "m588": {
        "cost": 9
    },
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь, задачу начал делать на PHP, для этого установил WAMP server

Comment: $id_col переменная где тут в коде?
"12 раз данные указанные в блоке записи в строку" - где они указаны в коде?

Comment: Поправил код.
И вот данные которые ксерятся
    // Записать строку текста
    fwrite($f, 
    "\t\t\t\"m$id_col\": {\n"
    ."\t\t\t\t\"cost\": $cost\n"
    ."\t\t\t},"
    );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
$offset = 100; //Смещение по айди - последний, например
$out = '';//Вывод текста
$costs_array = array(5,3,5,12,3,4,5,...,2); // Массив со значениями переменной
foreach($costs_array as $k => $v){
     $out .= "\t\t\t\"m".($k+$offest)."\": {\n"
     ."\t\t\t\t\"cost\": $v\n"
     ."\t\t\t},";
}
fwrite($f,$out);
...
```

Но вообще конечно да, таким образом JSON юзать не есть гут.

[Из массива В строку](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php/).

[Из строки - в массив](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Сработало, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
// Записать строку текста
fwrite($f, 
"\t\t\t\"m$test\": {\n"
."\t\t\t\t\"cost\": 9\n"
."\t\t\t},"
);
```

Это что за ужас?

Конечно имеются более изящный способ.

Сперва вам надо понять, что JSON - это всего лишь одно из возможный представлений данных и он не подходит для обработки в PHP без преобразования его в стандартный объект PHP (ну либо еще можно поплакать, помучиться, но съесть кактус приправив его регулярными выражениями и работой со строками)

Для преобразования JSON в объект PHP и обратно есть функции [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php) И [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php)

Первая преобразует текст, содержащий JSON, в (многомерный) массив PHP. Вторая наоборот - массив в строку, содержащую JSON.
\

Пример

```
$array = ["m577"=>["cost"=>8],"m578"=>["cost"=>9],"m579"=>["cost"=>1]];
$encoded = json_encode($array);
$decoded = json_decode($encoded);
print_r($encoded);
echo PHP_EOL;
print_r($decoded);
```

Вывод

```
{"m577":{"cost":8},"m578":{"cost":9},"m579":{"cost":1}}
stdClass Object
(
    [m577] => stdClass Object
        (
            [cost] => 8
        )

    [m578] => stdClass Object
        (
            [cost] => 9
        )

    [m579] => stdClass Object
        (
            [cost] => 1
        )

)
```

[sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ca5aec17b368515ad1c10df5207d5bc7adb64410)

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Да мой пример, получается тихий ужас, сейчас попробую разобраться с вашим и почитать про json_encode/decode. Мне главное что бы в итоге в файл прилетала информация как указал в примере, потому-что ее потом "ручками" приходится вставлять в основной JSON с кол-вом строк over 60000